# How to change font-size for a grammar declaration

Tags: fontsize, syntax, grammar

I have a grammar declaration like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{syntax}
\begin{document}
...
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{grammar}
            <A> ::= `<--' <B> <C> `-->'

            <B> ::= <D>

            ...
        \end{grammar}
        \caption{A sample grammar}
        \label{fig:sample-grammar}
    \end{figure}
...
\end{document}
```

LaTeX uses a superfluously large font to render it and some lines do not even fit on the page and need to be wrapped, which has a bad impact on clarity.

How do I change font-size only for the grammar?

Comment: In my test the font size is the same as outside the environment. Can you add a complete (compilable) example that shows the problem?

Comment: It is probably the same as in the outside environment, but as both the non-terminals and the terminals are all upper-case (which means all words in fact), it appears to be bigger. I would like it to be smaller than the default font-size, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\AtBeginEnvironment` from `etoolbox`. But, please, always add a complete example with all packages needed. I'm guessing you're using `syntax`, as I don't know other packages that provide a `grammar` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{grammar}{\small}
\begin{document}
Some text before and
some text before and
some text before and
some text before and
some text before and
some text before and
some text before and
some text before
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \begin{grammar}
        <A> ::= `<--' <B> <C> `-->'

        <B> ::= <D>

    \end{grammar}
    \caption{A sample grammar}
    \label{fig:sample-grammar}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Don't use the `[h!]` option alone for the `figure` environment. You're basically telling LaTeX to run out of space if one of the figures can't be placed where you'd like it to be.

[image]